# Merge multiple dataframes into a single column

Tags: r, data.table

Hello guys I'm here again to ask  you some questions.

I've "n" separated csv with only two columns temperature and date in format dmy HM, these documents are from a single digital Thermometer which only can store 4 months at time.
I would like to read all these documents and put their variable temperature into a new df (Union)just in a single column.

In order to make a single document,  I created a df named "date" with a date-time sequence bigger than any other csv to union this "n" documents with the column "Date" to paste the value when the dates are the same.

My inputs are like this:

```
Date<- seq(as.POSIXlt("2017-01-01 00:00:00", tz="UTC"),
     as.POSIXlt("2017-03-01 00:00:00", tz="UTC"), 
     by="60 min")
temp = runif(1417, min = 32, max = 100)
df1 <- data.frame(Date,temp)

Date<- seq(as.POSIXlt("2017-03-01 00:00:00", tz="UTC"),
     as.POSIXlt("2017-06-01 00:00:00", tz="UTC"), 
     by="60 min")
temp = runif(2209, min = 32, max = 100)
df2 <- data.frame(Date,temp)
```

So, it's the big sequence which I made to union my df's with.

```
Date <- seq(as.POSIXlt("2017-01-01 00:00:00", tz="UTC"),
       as.POSIXlt("2017-07-01 00:00:00", tz="UTC"), 
       by="60 min")
date <- data.frame(Date)
```

I was trying with the library `data.table` as follow:

```
setDT(date)
setDT(df1)
Union<-df1[date, on="Date"])
```

This worked just with 1 df, but, How can I  get a way to automate the multiple merge from my 2 df just into that single column which was made in Union.

I hope you can help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to generate some sample data to show how to use `Reduce` and `merge`. I'm assuming you want a 'wide' format, with a column for each location.

```
set.seed(123)

# list of 10 data.tables with columns date and temp

ldat <- lapply(1:10, function(x) data.table(date = sample(seq(as.Date('2016/01/01'), as.Date('2016/01/31'), by="day"), 12),
                                            temp = runif(12, min = 32, max = 100)))

# right now, each table in the list has the same column name
# change the 'temp' column name to the location it was collected

loc_vect <- c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", 
              "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas")

ldat <- lapply(1:10, function(x) setnames(ldat[[x]], c("date", "temp"), c("date", loc_vect[x])))
```

That's the sample data. Now to put it together using merge.

```
# now merge all of them within Reduce

dat <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, 
                                   y, 
                                   all = TRUE, 
                                   by = "date"), 
              ldat, 
              accumulate = FALSE)
```

The output is:

```
          date  Alabama   Alaska  Arizona Arkansas California Colorado Connecticut  Indiana     Iowa   Kansas
 1: 2016-01-01       NA 47.84632       NA 61.57271         NA       NA          NA       NA       NA       NA
 2: 2016-01-02 34.86005       NA 58.10994       NA         NA       NA          NA       NA       NA 45.44664
 3: 2016-01-03       NA       NA 86.01528 76.41093   42.00244 61.88134    46.82337       NA       NA       NA
 4: 2016-01-04       NA 60.18915 62.49911       NA         NA 98.62789          NA       NA 64.77890       NA
 5: 2016-01-05       NA       NA 87.24249       NA         NA       NA          NA       NA       NA       NA
 6: 2016-01-06       NA       NA       NA 55.35912         NA       NA    68.29078 50.02121 46.70533       NA
 7: 2016-01-07       NA       NA       NA 92.72748         NA 76.86901    46.74871       NA       NA       NA
 8: 2016-01-08       NA 41.71040 74.78704       NA         NA       NA    47.03500 53.24648       NA 68.86146
 9: 2016-01-09 78.07480       NA 77.22783 40.88731   96.44543 67.43723    56.17029 94.09680       NA 88.57107
10: 2016-01-10 99.61034 63.68545       NA       NA         NA 82.12129          NA       NA       NA       NA
11: 2016-01-11 79.11063       NA       NA 92.27990         NA       NA          NA       NA 43.60388 79.48179
12: 2016-01-12 38.99888       NA       NA       NA   69.35136       NA    57.48055 93.32746       NA 86.63246
13: 2016-01-13 92.48867       NA 50.65809       NA   81.00055       NA          NA 89.10421 35.24113 94.26648
14: 2016-01-14 54.29861       NA       NA 98.97707   95.60039 32.71176          NA       NA 51.60027       NA
15: 2016-01-15       NA       NA 87.08438 76.65955   52.48357       NA          NA 70.39215       NA       NA
16: 2016-01-16       NA 53.63631       NA 43.90358         NA 59.84430          NA       NA       NA       NA
17: 2016-01-17       NA 47.75055 61.90855       NA   36.12900       NA          NA 50.02223       NA 59.00633
18: 2016-01-18       NA 41.43881       NA       NA         NA 44.50177          NA       NA 43.70768       NA
19: 2016-01-19       NA       NA 83.30431       NA         NA       NA          NA 80.16374 91.85676 49.73827
20: 2016-01-20       NA       NA       NA       NA   96.87820       NA    56.06551 64.72771       NA       NA
21: 2016-01-21 75.55446 83.57525       NA       NA         NA 77.76394          NA       NA       NA       NA
22: 2016-01-22 96.90625 46.71574 87.39552       NA   71.81287       NA    76.19899 53.86083 77.85759       NA
23: 2016-01-23       NA       NA       NA 38.99480   41.67601       NA          NA       NA       NA       NA
24: 2016-01-24 70.93907       NA       NA       NA         NA       NA          NA 72.41534       NA 74.04788
25: 2016-01-25 93.18810 60.13325       NA 53.78538   59.92690 53.19575          NA       NA       NA 35.97654
26: 2016-01-26 48.73397       NA 38.44916 44.76300         NA 85.46715          NA       NA       NA 61.13266
27: 2016-01-27       NA       NA       NA       NA         NA       NA    70.89160       NA 79.65801       NA
28: 2016-01-28       NA       NA       NA       NA         NA       NA    82.34274       NA 56.75825       NA
29: 2016-01-29       NA 42.36624       NA       NA         NA       NA    66.15637 50.64333 49.20162       NA
30: 2016-01-30       NA 57.08149       NA       NA         NA 87.88277    62.24422       NA       NA       NA
31: 2016-01-31       NA       NA       NA       NA   59.50670       NA          NA       NA 59.37499 42.39633
          date  Alabama   Alaska  Arizona Arkansas California Colorado Connecticut  Indiana     Iowa   Kansas
```

If you want it in a 'tall' format (only two columns for date, temp, and possibly a third for location), that would be even easier by adding a 'location' column and using `rbindlist(dat)`. But, going from the current table, you can use melt.

```
melt(dat, 
     id.vars = "date", 
     variable.name = "Location", 
     value.name = "Temp")[!is.na(Temp)]
```

Resulting in:

```
           date Location     Temp
  1: 2016-01-02  Alabama 34.86005
  2: 2016-01-09  Alabama 78.07480
  3: 2016-01-10  Alabama 99.61034
  4: 2016-01-11  Alabama 79.11063
  5: 2016-01-12  Alabama 38.99888
 ---                             
116: 2016-01-19   Kansas 49.73827
117: 2016-01-24   Kansas 74.04788
118: 2016-01-25   Kansas 35.97654
119: 2016-01-26   Kansas 61.13266
120: 2016-01-31   Kansas 42.39633
```

Comment: Wow mate your answer is amazing and works for my next step, but is not what I need.
All the documents that i need to put in a single columns are observations from a single digital thermometer which just can store 4 months of observations.  

So,based on your example; I need something like setting sequences of 4 different months for each data frame where date never intersect each other, but i would like to have bigger date-time sequence which will show me NA when the information is none .Then merge all the temperature data into a single column

Comment: I'm having trouble picturing what you're trying to do. Can you provide a couple example documents, and the output you would want to get from combining them?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking without a sample data set and desired solution.  You can use `stack()` to set columns on top of each other like so:

```
> x <- data.frame(x = seq(1,3), y = seq(11,13), z = seq(21,23))
> x
  x  y  z
1 1 11 21
2 2 12 22
3 3 13 23
> stack(x)
  values ind
1      1   x
2      2   x
3      3   x
4     11   y
5     12   y
6     13   y
7     21   z
8     22   z
9     23   z
```

I'm making the assumption that x,y,z would be different weather stations in your example and this is after you have created one single large table and want to have a two column dataset from that master table.